# Is it possible to recover after completely botching my best chances to get a PhD?

Tags: phd, research-process, advisor

I'm currently a master's student in computer science, thinking about applying to PhD programs. As I detailed in [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95809/should-i-leave-out-research-in-my-nsf-fellowship-application-if-im-not-getting/95926#95926), I had the audacity to ask my advisor why he hadn't let me work on projects that he allowed other students with equivalent qualifications to work on and instead had me working on a project that, according to one of his co-authors, was not publishable (it was more of an industry thing and they were just going to stick it on the internet somewhere). In response, **he <strike>fired me from my</strike> gave someone else the TA position he had said I would have and now isn't even responding to my emails**. (And he refused to answer any of the questions I'd asked him, btw.)

**Is it even possible to salvage my chances of getting into a top PhD program after this?** He's a famous professor and very well regarded in his field. A letter of recommendation from him would have been CRITICAL in my applications to PhD programs. Now, I not only don't have a publication to my name, but have NOTHING to show for a project I worked three months on. I know that conflicts between advisors and students are typical, but do they typically result in a totally burned bridge without even a LOR? Presumably, my potential bridges with everyone he knows (several professors in other schools) are also burned for me as well!

I suppose I can try to find someone else in the department to do research with, but

1. this setback has delayed my application by at least a year, and
2. the only professor in my area who seems nice enough to work with is a very junior professor, and my understanding is that [a LOR from a well-known professor is critical](http://web.archive.org/web/20150616152158/http://matt-welsh.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/so-you-want-to-go-to-grad-school.html). (I've met all the other professors in my school in my chosen specialty and they all come off as complete assholes.)

I am left with a few questions:

1. Did I just completely blow my chances? If not, **how can I possibly get on my feet to be a competitive PhD applicant by next year?**
2. **How is it possible to find a nice, supportive advisor??** I had done my due diligence: I talked to several of my advisor's students, and they had nothing but good things to say about him. I'm not sure what other sources I could possibly find. A friend of mine did the same with a different advisor, only for his true colors to come out after several months of working with him as well. Is it really just a roll of the dice, where even if I get into a PhD program, odds are the advisor is going to turn out to be an asshole?
3. **In the future, am I just supposed to keep my mouth shut even if I have reservations about the project I'm working on?**

UPDATE: This experience (and a couple others) soured me on academia completely and I ended up going into industry instead. So far so good.

Comment: You were a Masters student, so having an industry project to show instead of a paper is not a bad thing. Your depiction of the case, unfortunately, sends off a message of entitlement. Your enemy in the present case, as described in your question is not your former advisor. If there were other things not discussed, my opinion may yet shift.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Sorry, in the interest of keeping this post short, I wasn't fully clear on what happened: the co-author said this during a meeting with the advisor; he wasn't "inveigling" me against him. Secondly, I actually didn't bring up his comment during my discussion with my advisor; I just said that since I was looking to apply to PhD programs, I was hoping to get on a project where I could contribute something novel rather than simply coding up what they had already come up with. And I was confused and hurt that people with my same background were given that opportunity and I wasn't.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I am in no way insinuating that I don't think I was in the wrong here. Although I think never talking to me again is an overreaction, the very title of my post refers to *my* having completely botched this.

Comment: Ok, point taken. It's not easy to get out of such a situation. You can see if you can find some friendly prof somewhere in the faculty - or tone down your expectations about the ranking of the school. There are some less known places with good and interesting research.

Comment: _a LOR from a well-known professor is critical._ — "Well-known" and "junior" are not opposites!  In particular, most junior faculty in strong departments are well known, and most senior faculty in weak departments are not.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs _sends off a message of entitlement_ — **I couldn't disagree more strongly.**  OP *is* entitled to ask his advisor why he wasn't given more interesting work.  Moreover, OP *is* entitled to an honest and well-considered answer.  I find your suggestion that OP is somehow responsible for his advisor's tantrum offensive.

Comment: @JeffE Thank you so much; both of your comments make me feel so much more hopeful and less like I need to whip myself over this.

Comment: @JeffE I had a bit of a conversation with the OP about that (it is still around). He convinced me that this was not intended this way (see my later response). To me, the original formulation of the question, without the context of prior developments, was ambiguous. Please note that I had qualified my statement on (then) possibly lacking information.

Comment: @JeffE: I mostly agree with your post, but note that a partial cause that contributed to the advisor's tantrum *may* have been the OP's previous own "tantrum" ("I was confused and hurt that people with my same background were given that opportunity and I wasn't." - the way I read this, at least, they actually said it like that).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper No, I didn't say that. I simply asked why I couldn't do a project like those other ones. I mentioned in that comment that I felt hurt in response to the accusation that I felt entitled. But I won't hide the fact that I subsequently did have something of a tantrum: I noticeably went out of my way to avoid him in the following days and privately expressed my frustration to one of his students (a friend of mine). If that's sufficient grounds for being permanently blacklisted, then so be it, but it still seems like a gross overreaction to me.

Comment: @user124384: "And I was confused and hurt that people with my same background were given that opportunity and I wasn't." and "I felt hurt in response to the accusation that I felt entitled" look like two quite different statements to me (both from your comments), but it's good to know you didn't literally say you felt hurt, thereby possibly exerting some pressure and exhibiting possibly unrealistic expectations (that the professor can summon projects at will to make everyone happy). Without such an implication, I fully agree with JeffE in that the professor is overreacting.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper No. Sorry, I'm still not making myself clear. One of the commenters accused me of feeling entitled. However, I claim that I did not feel entitled; I felt confused and hurt by the fact that I wasn't given a different project. If there was a valid reason that those other people were given those other projects, or even if it was arbitrary, then fine. I just wanted an explanation since it seemed rather unfair from my perspective.

Comment: @user124384 - Have you spoken with a department administrator?

Comment: @aparente001 I have an appointment with one in two weeks. I might try to find someone with better availability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(1) If you're in computer science, then even failing to get into a PhD program immediately after finishing your master's degree is not an insurmountable road block. There are even industry projects you can work on to improve your application.

(2) Yes, it is ultimately a roll of the dice. Some advisors are, in fact, just assholes who will ruin your career, and there's no amount of due diligence that will completely remove the chance of finding one. It's horribly unfair that a choice that will determine your career and entire life will depend on making a random die roll, but there's really nothing you can do about it; you have little power as a prospective grad student. (And don't expect much understanding or sympathy here; this board is mostly composed of people who have made that roll, and don't realize the amount of luck involved or that there was a die roll in the first place. The same remark applies to a wide variety of such die rolls in life.)

(3) Few people will say so explicitly, but yes. You have little power in the advsior/student relationship; and as a student (and not even one of his PhD students), you're probably beneath his notice. It is also massively unfair, but see point (2).

Comment: Then I'm not interested in getting a PhD. If I have to kiss someone's ass, I'd rather be paid 6 figures while doing so.

Comment: Well, the upside is that if it does work out, it's the perfect job: You get to work on legitimately challenging, original research (which is impossible outside academia in some fields, such as mathematics), have the time and support to do so, and get to pursue your own goals and research interest. The downside is that getting there comes down to a matter of luck (although I'm sure most people here would insist that you can avoid the dice through sheer force of will--- and if it doesn't work out, then you must not be talented enough or want it enough).

Comment: +100 for "don't expect much sympathy or understanding here"...so true!!

Comment: While I generally agree with this answer (and upvoted it), this community is *also* filled with people who have seen their fair share of unreasonable students, so I think many of the senior members here take a somewhat balanced view on a situation that they only know one side of. *(and, philosophically speaking, Stack Exchange is not and is not trying to be a place to get comfort, it's a place to get actionable recommendations)*

Comment: That said, I agree and have always agreed that we, as a group, often forget about survivor bias.

Comment: @xLeitix: Definitely agree that stackexchangeable isn't and shouldn't be a place to look for sympathy from, but I am annoyed by the preponderance of answers (on other questions) that boil down to, "Well, things will magically work out if you're talented enough and try hard enough; and if they don't, then you must not have been good enough or wanted it enough." It's like a board full of lottery winners telling people that they just need to keep buying more lottery tickets.

Answer (score 5):

It looks that your relations with this professor are coming to an end, and you can't rely on his future support. That's a shame; however, there's still a plenty of fish in a water, and hopefully enough time to get some.

1. Why don't you focus on establishing some contacts with another professor or lecturer in your university? Maybe someone slightly less senior and/or less famous, but still sufficiently established so that their LOR would matter? You probably attend classes of other professors, perhaps doing some sort of projects with some of them? Could it be expanded into a collaboration resulting in a publication or a research report?

   Are there other TA/RA positions advertised? Or maybe someone is seeking an hourly-payed students to collect some data for their experiment? A professor is running a Math Society or a club?
2. You probably did your homework studying this professor really well, but sometimes the relations simply does not work out. Maybe he is not a very good person; maybe you could've been a little bit more delicate (or cautious) with the language you chose to make your inquires. Maybe you should've waited until the contract is signed before hinting your unhappiness with the arrangements. It is impossible to say at the moment; and there are more urgent matters pressing. The understanding will eventually come.
3. Many people adopt the strategy of "keeping your mouth shut" and are successful in academia. Many did not, and they are successful, too. Academia is diverse, and in parts it is still a place where academics are allowed to be weird and insubordinate as long as they deliver outstanding research and excellent teaching. But the flip side is of course that sometimes someone else is behaving inappropriately led by his/her ego, or a sense of entitlement, or simply as a result of heavy sleep deprivation, and you occasionally become a collateral damage. It is important to remember that we all are people and try to treat others in the same way you would like to be treated yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a student in the US, consider reaching out to your institution's ombuds services. They are usually an informal and neutral third party that can arbitrate disputes such as this. Although I can't elaborate on the terms of your termination (what does your contract say, are you at will?), knowing of this avenue of resolution may serve you well.

Comment: "Fired" was a quick, dramatic way of describing it. The full story is that I hadn't signed my contract yet. He had told me that he'd chosen me to TA for him, and then after our discussion occurred, I discovered that he had given the position to someone else without telling me. Regardless, though, talking to an ombudsman is a great idea, thanks.

Comment: Fired =/= not hired. Since you never signed the contract, I presume he never signed, and HR never signed, I can reasonably presume that you were never an employee (TA) in any capacity.

Comment: Your presumption is incorrect.

Comment: Being promised a job =/= does not mean you will actually get it. The employment contract is not valid unless all parties pertaining to it sign in agreement.

Comment: I never said anything about what my assumptions were. I simply reported what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Some profs lord their power over their students as they have the student future in their hands. This gives them a sense of God"ish" power and when its questioned, some profs act out. The result can be something like this. Even asking fair questions of them, can drive them in to a passive/aggressive rage. They may not raise their voice, but you'll know you've stepped in it when they don't reply to your emails and won't respond about your thesis.

Sadly, the best course of action may be to simply play the game and go throw yourself on the mercy of Mr. God and appeal to his vanity/ego. With such folks, that is usually their softest spot. :)

Todd

Comment: Thanks, this echoes what a professor friend of mine had to say about the incident. I'm unable to appeal to his ego, however, if he won't respond to my emails. I already sent an apology, with no answer. I've thought about going to his office, but that seems like a bad idea under the circumstances.